# UI and some functions not working after deleting xcworkspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

My project uses CocoaPods and unfortunately, I deleted the `.xcworkspace` file. After I run `pod install` again, I can build the project and run it; but some functions are not working: the user cannot tap the button, image, or tableview, and the animation is not working.

Please help me!

UPDATE: sorry for my fault. I save `NSURL` by `setValue: forKey` in `NSUserDefaults`
 cause this problems!

Answer (score 0):

delete xcworkspace and Pods Directory (do not delete podfile)

open terminal and browse to project folder
pod install